# Open native maps app in windows phone 8.1 with center to specific point

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I want to launch Maps app on a button click and center the view to a specific point. In JSON file I have many items and each has latitude and longitude property. And I want to center the map to those properties. I can lauch app like this

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string uriToLaunch = "bingmaps:?cp=40.726966~-74.006076&lvl=10";
        var uri = new Uri(uriToLaunch);
        var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri);
    }
```

But how can I replace for example 40.726966 and -74.006076 with my latitude and longitude properties?
I have tried this

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SampleDataItem item;
        string uriToLaunch = "bingmaps:?cp="+item.Latitude+"~"+item.Longitude+"&lvl=10";
        var uri = new Uri(uriToLaunch);
        var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri); 
    }
```

I get an an exception for using unassigned variable item. Any clues of how to make this work?

Comment: You never assign a value to `item`

Comment: @peter Yes I know, but I have all values for each item assigned and stored in my json file, so I dont want to assign new values, because I would only create a new item. So how can I have each item´s latitude and longitude accessible? I am just a beginner, so this may be very easy. And thanks for reply.

Comment: Do you have the code that loads the JSON? If you share that also, we can probably help fill in the missing pieces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your button is for each item in list or button should have datacontext so that it can get which item to use for showing map or you can manually assign value to item variable. Then your code should be

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SampleDataItem item=(sender as Button).DataContext as SampleDataItem;
if(item!=null){
        string uriToLaunch = string.Format("bingmaps:?cp={0}~{1}&lvl=20&collection=point.{2}_{3}_{4}", context.latitude, context.longitude, context.latitude, context.longitude, title);
        var uri = new Uri(uriToLaunch);
        var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri); 
    }}
```

The error is because item variable is not assigned any value and needs value by DataContext or direct assigning.

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I wanted. But now I have one more question. I want to show pointer on map to that location. I know how to add it to MapControl, but how to add it to opened Maps App?

Comment: I have updated my answer a bit with point location showing. It's not lot of change though.